# Help with expectation and infinite sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, expected-value

The problem states:

## Find the expectation $f(x; θ) = θ(1 − θ)^{x-1}$ when x = 1, 2, 3.... and 0<θ<1

I know I have to evaluate $$(x) = \sum_{x=1}^\infty xθ(1 − θ)^{x-1}$$

It sums to $$1/θ$$ but I don't understand why. What rule am I missing here? Sorry for formatting issues, I am learning

Answer (score 4):

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty x\theta(1-\theta)^{x-1}=-\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sum_{x=1}^\infty (1-\theta)^x\right)=-\theta\frac d{d\theta}\left(\frac{1-\theta}{1-(1-\theta)}\right)=-\theta\frac d{d\theta}\left(\frac1\theta-1\right)=\frac1\theta.$$

See also: [Geometric Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series)

Comment: If I wanted to evaluate (x^2), how does the extra x factor in? Thank you for your help

Comment: Using the same method, taking the second derivative of $\sum (1-\theta)^x$ will give you $\sum x(x-1)(1-\theta)^{x-2}.$ Now, you know $\sum x(1-\theta)^{x-1},$ so you can figure out $\sum x^2(1-\theta)^{x-1}$ too.